# Syncing two android projects

Tags: java, android, json, url

I am using two different android projects downloaded from internet, and assembled them to make them into one single project.

they both are online apps, and they are using JSONparser and urls to connect , but sort of in a different way,

will it be required to compile the jsonparser files of both projects to compile into one or , i can keep them separate as they are in the same project.

let me tell u, one project is of login,register system...... and the second is of account management

they are in process to sync to function dependent on kind of each other

all mean to ask is can one android project have two or more jsonparser.java classes in different packages or not?

Comment: Do you use `AndroidStudio` or `Eclipse`? `Gradle` or `Ant`?

Answer (score 0):

> can one android project have two or more jsonparser.java classes in
>   different packages or not?

Yes, this is possible.

[image]